# How to deal with errors on select with multiple IO steams?

Tags: python, io

I have the following call to select:

```
try:
    rlst, wlst, plst = select.select(
        [x.fileno() for x in self.rlist],
        [x.fileno() for x in self.wlist], 
        [x.fileno() for x in self.plist])
except select.error, err:
    [...]
```

Where `self.rlist`, `self.wlist`, and `self.plist` are lists of IO streams (either sockets, PIPE, files, whatever).  Now, I am assuming that this select could fail when one of the streams fails for whatever reason.

How can I find out which of those streams caused the error?  What I really want to do is remove that IO stream from its list and continue with the select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the [Socket Programming HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/sockets.html):

> One very nasty problem with select: if somewhere in those input lists of sockets is one which has died a nasty death, the select will fail. You then need to loop through every single damn socket in all those lists and do a `select([sock],[],[],0)` until you find the bad one. That timeout of 0 means it won’t take long, but it’s ugly.